# JavaScript Destructive Map Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, map-function

I'm trying to make this map function a more destructive version of itself. Meaning the map function modifies the original array instead of a new one.

```
function map (array, callback) {
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result.push(callback(array[i]))
  }
  console.log("Array",array, "Result",result)
  return result
}
```

The console.log returns:

```
   Array [ 5, 2, 1 ] Result [ 6, 3, 2 ]
```

The array should be [5,2,1] and it's currently [6,3,2]

Comment: If you are aiming for inplace modification then don't return anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `var result = []` creates a new array. If you want to modify the old array, you should *assign* to it (assign to properties of the `array` parameter):

```js
function map (array, callback) {
  array.forEach((item, i) => {
    array[i] = callback(item);
  });
  return array;
}

const arr = [1, 2];
map(arr, e => e + 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Note that calling this function `map` might be a bit misleading, because `Array.prototype.map` does something similar, but creates an *entirely separate array*, like your original code is doing. You might want to call this function something other than `map`, perhaps `changeEvery` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this code...I hope your problem solved**

```
function map(array, callback) {
    var result=[]
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       result.push(callback(array[i]))
    }
    console.log(result)
}
map([5, 2, 1], (value) => {
   return value
})
```

Comment: thanks for answering to the OP ; however, this being an answer to a rather old question, you may edit your post and explain a bit your answer.